# Why Linear Discriminant analysis in MATLAB and R are producing different results

Tags: r, matlab, discriminant-analysis, manova

I am applying manova and lda to my data 12 samples (6 groups with 2 samples in each) and  6 measurements.

I used lda form MAS5 package in R and different LDA functions in MATLAB. They all gave me different coefficients for the same data.

R code

```
data.lda <- lda(num, gr)
data1=as.data.frame(coef(data.lda))

data1

LD1        LD2        LD3         LD4         LD5         LD6
1.18238008 -1.6777451 -0.4044603  0.80635013 -0.01091674 -0.09999003
-7.05677579 -0.9670866  0.1010412  2.81653252 -0.41865802  0.29296099
-0.06181053  0.2747723  0.1089152  0.01921334 -0.46895867 -0.10802942
-0.53263363 -0.4758837  0.3215393 -0.22113722 -0.16328353  0.50041180
7.58473007  0.3115666  1.3149100 -1.15974586  0.57505267 -0.15912359
-11.89174701 -2.7545665 -0.6972937  0.90213995 -0.94043893 -0.32567038
```

MATLAB

```
function [Y, W, lambda] = LDA2(X, L)
    Classes=unique(L)';
    k=numel(Classes);
    n=zeros(k,1);
    C=cell(k,1);
    M=mean(X);
    S=cell(k,1);
    Sw=0;
    Sb=0;
    for j=1:k
        Xj=X(L==Classes(j),:);
        n(j)=size(Xj,1);
        C{j}=mean(Xj);
        S{j}=0;
        for i=1:n(j)
            S{j}=S{j}+(Xj(i,:)-C{j})'*(Xj(i,:)-C{j});
        end
        Sw=Sw+S{j};
        Sb=Sb+n(j)*(C{j}-M)'*(C{j}-M);
    end
    [W, LAMBDA]=eig(Sb,Sw);
    lambda=diag(LAMBDA);
    [lambda, SortOrder]=sort(lambda,'descend');
    W=W(:,SortOrder);
    Y=X*W;
end
```

and the result is

```
W =

   -5.1992   -2.5162    0.8527    0.6897    0.0200    0.2825
   -3.8115   -1.6608    0.5880    0.4780   -0.6272    0.5420
   -1.6679   -0.6245   -0.1921    0.0693    0.0296    0.1814
   15.0545    1.4381    1.5472   -0.7139    0.0835    0.2780
  -12.0387   -1.2477   -0.6547   -0.0954   -0.0528   -0.0943
   13.4102    1.5279    1.4953    0.0684    0.3226    0.3852
```

Not only values but direction is also different. Does anybody know why and how to solve the problem?